# Updating ListView using ArrayAdapter after removing/inserting rows in database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, arraylist

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    teachersData=new TeachersData(this);  


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ArrayList<Data> classid=teachersData.listClass();
    ArrayAdapter<Data> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Data>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classid);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

---

```
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        String className = edit.getText().toString();
                        teachersData.insert(null, className, 0, 0, null);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), className + " Added.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        dialog.cancel();
                   }
               })
```

I presume it involves notifyDataSetChanged() from my searching so far but I can't figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `notifyDataSetChanged()` at point you have updated the data and you want to display the new data. When you have the new data you do `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Data>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classid);` (again) which means you are feeding the adapter with new data, and then you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to make `ListView` repopulate with the new data.

Answer (score 1):

You could call `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Data>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classid)` and then call `listView1.setAdapter(adapter)` which will cause the listview to refresh itself.